# parse text file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Pretty new to **XSLT 2.0**.

I have a snippet of code from a text file:

```
INSERT˝ITEM˝0180528˝ITEM˝304854˝˝STANDARD˝˝Towncar ˝061˝612˝123˝025˝Y˝0040928˝˝4000.95˝0˝0˝4000.95˝EA˝
INSERT˝CAR_STYLE˝18206˝COLOR˝Red
INSERT˝CAR_STYLE˝18206˝ENGINE˝V6
```

I want to generate an XML that produces:

```
<color>
    <colorId>Red</colorId>
    <description>Red</description>
<color>
```

I am trying to use **XSLT 2.0** to parse through the text file to gather this information and create the xml.  I will have to create multiple xslt files to parse the text, so getting a look at a simple example will help.

Comment: How do you intend to point the XSL transformation to the text file? Once you have that, it should be easy to use regex to extract any part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear how your input relates to the output, or what the actual structure/grammar of the input is. However the general approach is:

- Use the unparsed-text() function to read the input file
- Use tokenize() to split it into a sequence of lines.
- Use xsl:analyze-string to break up each line into its parts

Comment: Those steps helped a lot. Thanks!